# What does ">>>" operator do in Java

Tags: java

I recently gave an aptitude exam and encountered this piece of code:

```
public class MainClass{
    public static void main(String[] argv){
        int x = 0x80000000; 
        x = x >>> 31;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

At first I thought it must be some sort of error, but this gives a valid output of `1`. With `x >> 31`, the output is `-1`, which is understandable, but what does the extra `>` do?

Answer (score 1):

It's called [unsigned shift right](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) which means that it always fills in zeros regardless of the sign of the original int.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: https://www.javatpoint.com/operators-in-java.
The >>> operator is same as >> with an exception that it handles signed integers differently.